# relative positioned elements don't hide with jQuery hide() in IE 7

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to show and hide elements on my page with jQuery's `hide()` method, and it works perfectly in all browsers besides IE 7.  These elements are hidden when the page loads in the `jQuery(function($){}` method, and then can be later shown or hidden by the user.

In Internet Explorer, not all elements are hidden.  Some (so far, only buttons and divs) with a style `position:relative` remain when the page loads, though all the text inside of these elements is hidden.  After the page loads, I can click on the button that shows or hides these elements and they will then display correctly until the page reloads.

I have read that attaching a height style to these elements will fix similar bugs, but I tried this with no effect.  Does anybody know of something I could do to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

try

```
$(element-id/class).css("display","none");

$(element-id/class).css("display","inline");
```

instead of using .hide() method. The css property will surely work without doubts.

Comment: No luck, even applying this technique, there are still buttons that are not hidden when the page loads, only when I choose to hide them afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

You can work around this problem by applying 'visiblity : hidden' to those elements as well as hiding them. This will solve the problem for IE6 & IE7, like so:

```
$('#elementToHide').css("visibility", "hidden");
```

Then when needing to show it again, apply:

```
$('#elementToHide').css("visibility", "visible");
```

This works in conjunction with the normal use of .hide();